# Ember - how to clean up JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm pretty new to EmberJS and unfortunately I have to deal with JSON that doesn't include a root or ids and I can't seem to find any clear way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, which is just to clean up the response.

I assume that I need to be using an ember serializer to do this.

This is what I currently get from my `api/locations`:

```
[
  {
    "uri": "/location/1",
    "name": "ATLANTA"
  },
  {
    "uri": "/location/2",
    "name": "NORTH VIRGINIA"
  }
]
```

I assume that I need it to look like this instead, with a root and id's:

```
{
   "locations":[
     {
        "id":"1",
        "uri":"/location/1",
        "name":"ATLANTA"
     },
     {
        "id":"2",
        "uri":"/location/2",
        "name":"NORTH VIRGINIA"
     }
    ]
 }
```

I added a JSONSerializer under `app/serializers/location.js`

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
    // how can I manufacture an id here, say with index
    // how to I assign it to a root called "locations"
});
```

Just by including this JSONSerializer I do get a record in the store but it's only one and I assume that's because they don't have ids otherwise both entries would show up.

[image: only one record and no id]

I need help and examples of how to begin massaging this data. The examples I have tried didn't do anything.

Comment: This should help: http://www.codeandtechno.com/code/2015/7/5/transforming-json-payload-to-include-object-root-with-restadapter-in-emberjs

Comment: This will explain what you need: http://emberigniter.com/fit-any-backend-into-ember-custom-adapters-serializers/

Comment: Thanks fellas, codeandtechno is referencing deprecated or renamed methods than the version I'm working with. That solution is also a little hard for me to follow. And I came across emberigniter which they do provide some hints on how I might be able to do this but this looks likes it's for 2.0 and I'm working with 1.13. That's the other issue I kept hitting, different versions of the framework which will drive ya mad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that JSONSerializer fixes the root issue I mentioned but I was able to resolve my id issue by experimenting with the available methods on the serializer until I landed on something that worked. My final solution looks like this:

```
 export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({

    normalize: function(typeClass, hash) {
       hash['id'] = parseFloat(hash.uri.match(/\d+/g))
       return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    }

 });
```

Simple enough but, WOW, I couldn't find a single example that showed how to do something like this.